# Jquery show hide toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a script which slide toggles an element when clicked. Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accord").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".accordContent").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

However, when the screen resolution is below 790px I want the element to have a default of not showing. I tried this in a media query but then the above script doesn't work when below that resolution. Guess it confuses it and need something more in JQuery. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();

    if (winWidth < 790){
     $(".accordContent").hide();
}

    $(".accord").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".accordContent").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried this to make sure window has fully loaded and that just stops the functionality altogether. accordContent element is the element to be hidden(display:none) on default if screen < 790

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle, or show more of the code? It is possible you need to wait until the entire window has loaded not just the document with a $( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});

Comment: I updated the answer with what worked for me. This was only to initially hide the content of the ".accordContent"

Comment: Also, the width of that screen for me in the js fiddle was > 900, so I had to make a little smaller to test.

Comment: @ Adam That's working for me Adam. If you update your original code I'll vote you up. Thanks for your help